Can I improve my answer based on other answers?
The situation is this: recently, I answered a question here on CodeReview.SE.
I was the first to post, and my answer was pretty well-received (5 upvotes and originally accepted). I mainly redesigned the structure of the OP's code, and improved the code in some major aspects of software engineering (readability, reusability, maintainability, clarity, compatibility with potential larger projects, etc.).
Later, two new answers appeared. They also answered the question in a helpful and informative way, and their point of focus is on ones that I did not address. Conversely, one of the answers actually did state that their answer addresses topics that I did not address, and is "in addition to my answer".
One of the things they pointed out is very important, and I'm a bit ashamed that I did not realize it at first. I think that a complete answer should include it. So I was inclined to edit my answer to include that as well.
But, should I do that? Will I be flagged as plagiarism? Is this ethical and morally acceptable?
However, on CodeReview.SE I think everyone should be able to make their answer as complete as possible, as it's different from other programming sites like SO where every answer has their own unique approach in solving the problem. So should I do this? I'll appreciate any insights on this.

Note: This doesn't help much because the situation is a bit different. Firstly, I posted first, so I'm not trying to post another entire answer based to another person's answer, I'm just wishing to edit my post to also include their suggestions. Secondly, my answer encompasses more aspects than their answer, but I still think that the things pointed out by that answer are very important (I'm not trying to say that their answer is bad, it's the opposite. But it's undeniable that my answer was more complete).

One of my earliest answers basically was a write up of the improvements in another user's answer, as I found the explanation a bit lacking. The best part of getting multiple people to review your code is being able to see the vast differing of opinion and to be able to take the best parts of each when going forward. Whilst I do think improving an answer because of the points made in another answer is valid; if you don't noticeably improve on the point than you may take away the quality of both answers. I personally would upvote the other answer and move on to answering another question.

Including it just for the sake of including is pointless and detrimental. Are you planning on improving upon the points?

@Peilonrayz I just wanted to add those suggestions to my answer too. The actual situation is this: I posted my answer, got 5 upvotes and was accepted. Then, that answer and another one were posted. Today, I found that the score of both had exceeded mine and I got unaccepted eh?!!. So I thought that probably that's because I didn't include a few of the points in that other answer that OP thought was more important.

@Peilonrayz Anyway, although I may sound a bit selfish but I really think I deserve the accept.

@Peilonrayz I posted this question in a general sense, though, so I didn't mention the
actual situation. I would like to know if this is accepted and OK and will get my accept back, or if this is unacceptable and not OK and will only get me downvotes. Please help.

@LukeL I can't say for certain, but on average (so specific circumstances can result in the 'wrong' result) if the edit improves on the points and doesn't merely copy then the edit will be well received. However, if you don't post a good enough improvement then your edit will not be well received. And so you could lose upvotes including the accept. I have some concerns if you are chasing an accept rather than posting the best answer you may have a higher chance to post a not well received edit.

I would just give the first effort at the answer my best try. I do not edit my answers to include someone else's answer. It isn't fair and it may be plagiarism. As @Peilonrayz suggested, don't chase accepts. I have at least once had an accepted and told the OP of the question that another answer was better. I vote up many of the other answers.

Oh, thanks for everyone's suggestions! But does this warrant a downvote?

On meta downvotes to a question can mean "I disagree". Rather than "bad question". Given everyone seems to have reservations about the action you are suggesting taking; I would take the downvote as a please don't do what you are asking about doing.

Related: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5302/31562

Improving Existing Answers
I can't say for certain but on average the community will reward good contributions. I have a number of answers where I have taken a concept from one, or more, answers and given my best effort to better explain the situation but better.

Printing all possible sums of two n-sided dice rolls in which I provided a greater explanation of the cool algorithm another answer used.
Sum two integers, unless they are the same, in which case return double their sum in which I provided a better explanation of why using is is bad.
Reduce number of operations to get one array value in which I take a good approach, but make a minor change for vastly safer code.

All of my answers outscore the existing answers, and two even got accepted. As such the community has shown a clear intent to reward positive contributions. If you post the better answer you'll be rewarded.
Multiple Answers
I have always found the best experience when multiple answer are posted is when each answer focuses on a different problem. Each answer will be unique and give the asker a magnitude of areas to learn from.
And sometimes you'll posts an answer, and then the creator of the library will come out of nowhere and dunk on your answer. Which I've always liked, as then I can see somewhere I'm lacking, and can then improve my answers in the future.
I owe a lot of my skill to my peers. Seeing the wonderful and creative approaches of others has taught me much. And whilst seeing someone come later and dunk on my answer can give give rise to unpleasant feelings, you have to take the situation as a learning experience.
Current Situation
When I took ideas from other answers my rationale was "I find the answer lacking, I think I could do better." I found a problem, and my sole intent was to provide a solution. I didn't care if the community as a whole would reward me, as all I wanted was to better help the OP.

I found that the score of both had exceeded mine and I got unaccepted eh?!!. So I thought that probably that's because I didn't include a few of the points in that other answer that OP thought was more important.
Anyway, although I may sound a bit selfish but I really think I deserve the accept.
... I would like to know if this is accepted and OK and will get my accept back

We can see your rationale is to claw back something you feel you've lost. You're likely to merely copy other's ideas without improvement, taking away from the benefit of multiple answers. I believe you have an above average likelihood to be met in a negative light.

In my opinion, it doesn't seem like honest and respectful behavior when one contributor takes ideas and observations from other answers to the same question with no substantial changes. Because it belittles the efforts of other contributors.

I posted first

I guess you will agree that the ownership of ideas in question and the fact that your answer was posted first are unrelated.

a complete answer

From the perspective of the question-reader, the argument about an "answer as complete as possible", has no practical value. Because it forces a person interested in the problem to read the same suggestions multiple times (believe it or not, many people read all answers). And, again, it keeps the reader in the dark as to whom the merit of the ideas they found worthwhile belong.
Duplicating observations are also explicitly discouraged by our 101-how to answer manual:

Read the other answers so you don't cover duplicate points

The only exception is a situation when the answers containing identical points were written independently and posted almost at the same time.
Accept / Unaccept
OP has a special right to decide which answer is the most helpful to them personally. Accepting the answer is not mandatory (they might choose not to accept any), and they are not expected to justify their choice.
Also, OP has a right to withdraw the "green tick", and accept a different answer. This topic has been already discussed a couple of times:
Is Changing the Accepted Answer Frowned Upon?
Is it "bad" to unaccept an accepted answer?
Constructive use of Ideas from other answers

You might have a different perspective on the aspect of the problem than the contributor whose answer inspired you.

You can build up on the idea presented in another answer by enhancing or expanding it, making it more versatile and easier to use (note, that if it's a minor improvement, or bug-fix, it's better to leave a comment instead). And don't forget to upvote and acknowledge the value of the original idea in your answer.


Conclusion
Accept that you can miss something or get something wrong.
Don't overreact if someone points that out (regardless of whether they are correct, or not).

OK, thanks for the answer. I'm still pretty mad at the OP for unaccepting me, though.

@LukeL Such things like unaccept happen once in a while. OP is free to withdraw the green tick at any moment when they feel necessary, sometimes it results in a weird behavior. One of my answers on SO was repeatedly accepted / unaccepted 3 times with no activity on the page (no new answers, or comments). And some individuals are even attempting to abuse this feature by withdrawing their accepted mark and vote, aiming to manipulate the answerer into playing the role of a free mentor. It doesn't worth investing energy in pondering about such things (unless OP gives clear technical argumentation)

No OP didn't say anything at all. I asked for a reason, and nearly one month has passed with no response.

@LukeL "I asked for a reason" - I would not advise asking for a reason. You probably misinterpreted my comment. The main point is that OP's behavior in this case wasn't malicious or toxic, so it's best to just let it go.

@LukeL Asking about accepting / unaccepting answers isn't a good idea. The question of why OP found a particular answer most helpful to them personally and chosen it over the others is not a technical question. It rather belongs to the area of social interactions, because it depends on purely subjective criteria of OP deems helpful. Such requests can make them feel awkward and uncomfortable. And note that, OP is not obliged neither to accept any answer, nor justify their choice.

@LukeL Only if OP reaches out to you first, providing a technical reason (like: I tried your suggestion A, and it caused problem B), react accordingly. Otherwise, don't bother, there are many interesting questions and plenty of important things in real life.
